# Lost connection to MySQL server during query error with Rails3, octopus replication gem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, replication

I just upgrade my web service from Rails 2.3.8 to Rails 3.0.3

It's almost working well.

I has one problem, Lost connection error is occurred when the service is deployed with capistrano. About 3 times occurred every deployment. 
The service use octopus gem from https://github.com/tchandy/octopus for database replication with 1 master database and 2 slave database.

Mysql::Error: Lost connection to MySQL server during query: SELECT  `regions`.* FROM `regions` WH ...

The problem is not occurred when octopus is not used with single database. But replication is needed for traffic.

Please, give me any advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm the creator of Octopus.

Can you add this to your shards.yml file?

```
verify_connection: true
```

Also, if that don't work, try to configure rails to automatic reconnect:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/2_3_release_notes.html#reconnecting-mysql-connections

Obs: this will work only with mysql adapter, not mysql2.

Comment: Thank you! I am surprising you are creator of Octopus. You are right. it is one of the solutions. But, The problem cann't be solved with passenger. It is solved using Nginx + Unicorn.

Comment: I'm working to find a solution for Passenger! Also, nice to know that it solves your issue ;-)

Comment: You need to be careful with `verify_connection: true` because it can cause Octopus to make two SQL requests for every SQL request you actually make: one to verify the connection, plus the actual SQL request. In some applications, this will slow down your application.

Answer (score 1):

If your using Phusion Passenger and *PassengerSpawnMethod smart*.

```
# config/initializers/phusion_passenger.rb
if defined?(PhusionPassenger)
  PhusionPassenger.on_event(:starting_worker_process) do |forked|
    if forked
      # the following is *required* for Rails + "PassengerSpawnMethod smart".
      if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
        # force reconnect to "master" connection.
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect!

        # force reconnect to our octopus "slave" pools. This may include the "master" pool above.
        if defined?(Octopus)
          ActiveRecord::Base.connection_proxy.instance_variable_get(:@shards).each { |name, pool| pool.disconnect! }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This with:

```
# database.yml and shards.yml
reconnect: true
```